# How to show new QMainWindow in every loop in PyQT5?

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm trying to write a Python program using PyQt5 that will display a window in each iteration of the for loop. I would like to close after incrementing and displaying the next window. However, I do not know how to stop the loop every iteration and at the moment I am getting 6 windows at once.

main.py

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QLineEdit, QVBoxLayout, QMainWindow, 
    QWidget, QDesktopWidget, QApplication, QPushButton, QLabel, 
    QComboBox, QFileDialog, QRadioButton)
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, QByteArray
from alert import Window2
from test import test

class SG(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.resize(300, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('TEST')

        self.resultsGen = QPushButton('TEST', self)
        self.resultsGen.clicked.connect(lambda: self.on_click())

        self.show()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_click(self):
        test(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    sg = SG()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

alert.py

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QLineEdit, QVBoxLayout, QMainWindow, 
    QWidget, QDesktopWidget, QApplication, QPushButton, QLabel, 
    QComboBox, QFileDialog, QRadioButton)
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, QByteArray
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap

from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore

class Window2(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initPopup()

    def initPopup(self):
        self.resize(500, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle("Window22222")
        self.central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        lay = QVBoxLayout(self.central_widget)

        label = QLabel(self)
        pixmap = QPixmap('cropped/8.png')
        label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.resize(pixmap.width(), pixmap.height())

        lay.addWidget(label)

        self.textbox = QLineEdit(self)
        self.textbox.move(20, 20)
        self.textbox.resize(280, 40)

        # Create a button in the window
        self.button = QPushButton('Show text', self)
        self.button.move(20, 80)
        # connect button to function on_click
        self.button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.on_clickX())
        self.show()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_clickX(self):
        textboxValue = self.textbox.text()
        print(textboxValue)
        self.textbox.setText("")
        self.hide()
```

test.py

```
from alert import Window2

def test(self):
    for x in range(6):
        w = Window2()
```

Comment: Your question is unclear and your code is very confusing. What do you want to get? Do you want to show a new window as soon as the previous one is closed, until you reach the wanted number of shown windows?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as you run the for cycle, all the code of the initialization will be executed, which includes the `show()` call you used at the end of `initPopup()`.

A simple solution is to create a new signal that is emitted whenever you hide a window, and connect that signal to a function that creates a new one until it reaches the maximum number.

`main.py:`

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QPushButton
from alert import Window2

class SG(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
        self.alerts = []

    def initUI(self):
        self.resize(300, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('TEST')

        self.resultsGen = QPushButton('TEST', self)
        self.resultsGen.clicked.connect(self.nextAlert)

        self.show()

    def nextAlert(self):
        if len(self.alerts) >= 6:
            return
        alert = Window2()
        self.alerts.append(alert)
        alert.setWindowTitle('Window {}'.format(len(self.alerts)))
        alert.closed.connect(self.nextAlert)
        alert.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    sg = SG()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

`alert.py:`

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class Window2(QMainWindow):
    closed = pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initPopup()

    def initPopup(self):
        self.resize(500, 500)
        self.central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        lay = QVBoxLayout(self.central_widget)

        label = QLabel(self)
        pixmap = QPixmap('cropped/8.png')
        label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.resize(pixmap.width(), pixmap.height())

        lay.addWidget(label)

        self.textbox = QLineEdit(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.textbox)

        # Create a button in the window
        self.button = QPushButton('Show text', self)
        lay.addWidget(self.button)
        # connect button to function on_click
        self.button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.on_clickX())
        self.show()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_clickX(self):
        textboxValue = self.textbox.text()
        print(textboxValue)
        self.textbox.setText("")
        self.hide()
        self.closed.emit()
```

Just note that with this very simplified example the user might click on the button of the "SG" widget even if an "alert" window is visibile. You might prefer to use a QDialog instead of a QMainWindow and make the main widget a *parent* of that dialog.

`main.py:`

```
class SG(QWidget):
    # ...
    def nextAlert(self):
        if len(self.alerts) >= 6:
            return
        alert = Window2(self)
        # ...
```

`alert.py:`

```
class Window2(QDialog):
    closed = pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()
        self.initPopup()

    def initPopup(self):
        self.resize(500, 500)
        # a QDialog doesn't need a central widget
        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        # ...
```

Also, if an alert window is closed using the "X" button the new one will not be shown automatically. To avoid that, you can implement the "closeEvent" and ignore the event, so that the user will not be able to close the window until the button is clicked. As QDialogs can close themself when pressing the escape key, I'm also ignoring that situation.

`alert.py:`

```
class Window2(QMainWindow):
    # ...
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        event.ignore()

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() != Qt.Key_Escape:
            super().keyPressEvent(event)
```